# How do I limit the number of apache log files

Tags: apache2, log

I am using Ubunto 2018.4 VPS and using phpfpm 7.2-4. I have about 30 domains and each domain creates log files and archives them. It currently creates about 15 of each type (access/log) so there are literally hundreds of logs to sift through every time I need to.

So, my question is, is there a way to limit the number of archives that are saved from 3 max?

Many thanks
PS: I am not an advanced user so some linux talk will go right over my head, thanks again.

Comment: The archiving of the log files is probably not done by the Apache httpd server itself, but by a separate tool like [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate). You may want to look into your configuration of logrotate (or whatever similar tool you're using). There you can define which logfiles to rotate, when to rotate them, how many archived files to keep and so forth.

Comment: Thanks @Henning Kockerbeck i will look into it. I found it. It was in logrotate.d > apache file and set at 14. Thanks

Comment: Sounds great! I've elaborated a bit on my comment in an answer. Maybe you could accept the answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logs aren't archived, or [rotated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_rotation), by the Apache HTTPd server itself, but by a separate tool called [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate). Logrotate takes care of most logs. In addition to logs written by daemons like Apache HTTPd, MySQL or Postfix, it also rotates system logs like syslog, auth.log and so forth.

You may want to look into your logrotate configuration in `/etc/logrotate.conf` (the central config) and the files in `/etc/logrotate.d` (separate files for different logs). There you can configure which logfiles should be rotated, when to rotate them, how many archived files to keep and so forth.